# jQuery not validating email format

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

Quite a specific issue, this jQuery always logging to the console that the email format is invalid despite being a real address. Can't seem to figure out why. Is the regexp correct? Any help is hugely appreciated

```
    // VALIDATION ON BLUR
    $("#prospects_form > *").blur(function() {

        // Validate Email
        function valEmail() {
            var email = $("#form_email"),
                // Check address format
                emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

            if (!emailFilter.test(email.value)) {
                // Incorrect
                $("#form_email").addClass("invalid");
                console.log('email invalid');
            } else {
                // Correct
                $("#form_email").removeClass("invalid");
                console.log('email valid');
            }
        }
        valEmail();

    });
```

Comment: Seen as `var email` is a jQuery object you should try `email.val()` to get its value.

Comment: log or alert `email.value` and check that it is as expected.

Comment: FYI the regex looks valid: http://regex101.com/r/sH7wB0

Comment: A note: your RegExp will fail to match `something+deliver@domain.tld` and also domains with special chars would not be marked as valid. Also this part is a bit strange `([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+` there you say the last part after a `.` has one or more occurrence of 2-4 `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, while this would work for tlds with more then `4` chars, it looks strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment:

> Seen as var email is a jQuery object you should try email.val() to get
>   its value.

I made [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eq37w/) showing it working if you use `email.val()`.

```
if (!emailFilter.test(email.val())) {...
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery Dom object don't have a property `value`.

use this

```
$("#form_email").val();
```

instead of

```
$("#form_email").value;
```

Hope this helps....